# Why does the 'tail' command return the whole file content when using -c+1 or -c-1?

Tags: linux, bash

As the question itself, I cannot find out why `tail` acts that way.
I have a file named `myfile.txt` and its content is:

```
 firstline
 secondline
 thirdline
```

So when I use:

```
 tail -c-1 myfile.txt
```

or

```
 tail -c+1 myfile.txt
```

it outputs:

```
 firstline
 secondline
 thirdline
```

`man tail`:

> -c, --bytes = [+] NUM
>    output  the  last  NUM  bytes; or use -c +NUM to output starting
>    with byte NUM of each file

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- `tail -c+1 myfile.txt` is the same as `cat myfile.txt`: you're telling `tail` to start output with the *first* (`+1`) byte (`-c`), in other words: **the *whole file*.**
- `tail -c-1 myfile.txt` (more typically: `tail -c1 myfile.txt`) outputs only **the *last byte*** in `myfile.txt`.
  Assuming that `myfile.txt` is a properly formatted text file that ends with a trailing `\n`, and uses either a single-byte encoding such as ASCII or one that has single-byte ASCII encoding as a *subset*, such as UTF-8, this will output just that `\n`, i.e., a *blank line*.

To put **`tail`'s basic logic** in general terms (covers both the *GNU* and the *BSD/macOS* implementation):

<sup>Note:

- `tail` supports additional options not discussed here - see `man 1 tail`.

- In all forms below, *whitespace* between the option (`-<units>`) and its option-argument (`<count>` / `-<option>` or `+<index>`) is *optional* - this applies generically to POSIX-compatible utilities.</sup>

```
# Output <count> units *from the end* of the input.
# The following two forms are equivalent.
tail -<units>  <count>
tail -<units> -<count>
  # This next form is equivalent to: tail -n <line-count>.
tail -<line-count>

# Output everything *starting from* 1-based unit index <index>.
# In other words: Skip <index> - 1 units at the *start* of the input.
tail -<units> +<index>
```

- Option `-<units>` specifies the **units** for option-argument `<count>` / `<index>`.

  - **`-n`** refers to *lines*

    - Omitting `-<units>` and using only `-<count>` - note the required `-` prefix - is the same as `-n <count>`. (BSD/macOS `tail` also supports the form `+<count>` to imply `-n +<count>`, but GNU `tail` doesn't.)
  - **`-c`** refers to *bytes*(!) and is *not* UTF8-aware in either implementation.
  - BSD/macOS `tail` additionally supports **`-b`** for 512-byte *blocks*.
- If **`<count>` has no sign** (e.g., `1`), or an **explicit minus** (e.g., `-1`; never necessary), `<count>` units are returned **from the *end* of the input.**
- **A `+`-prefixed value** is taken as a **`1`-based(!) unit index** from the ***start* of the input** from which to output the input lines.
  In other words: `+<index>` means: **skip `<index> - 1` units at the beginning, and output all the rest**; e.g., `tail -n +2` outputs everything starting from - and *including* - the *2nd* line.
- **Omitting both `-<units>` and `<count>` / `-<count>` / `+<index>`** is the same as `tail -n 10`, meaning that `tail`'s default behavior is to output the input's ***last* `10` *lines*.**

---

If we apply this logic to the OP's follow-up question regarding the behavior of `-c+0` and `-c-0`:

- `-c+0` is treated the same as `-c+1` and therefore outputs the entire input (same as `cat`): you're asking for everything starting at the "zeroth" byte, which doesn't exist, but since `0 < 1`, with `1` being the first actual byte position, you still get the entire input as output.
- `-c-0` outputs nothing at all, because you're asking to return *zero* bytes (in other words: *nothing*) from the end of the input.

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu Xenial, perhaps a dummy question but, what happens with -c+0 or -c-0. I think it just take no bytes, isn't it? there must be a difference

Comment: Does any plain text file ends with "\n"?

Comment: @iqbal_cs: Re `-c+0` and `-c-0`: please see my update.

Comment: @iqbal_cs: Plain-text files (on Unix) _typically and customarily_ end in `\n`, but they don't have to. If they don't, however, some tools behave unexpectedly.

Comment: `tail -2 myfile.txt` returns "second line **\n** third line" BUT, `tail +3 myfile.txt` returns: "tail: cannot open '+3' for reading: No such file or directory **\n** ==>myfile.txt<== **\n** firstline **\n** secondline **\n** thirdline

Comment: @iqbal_cs: You must use `tail -n +3 myfile.txt` in that case; with `+`-prefixed numbers, _GNU_ `tail` (but not BSD/macOS `tail`) requires you to specify the units explicitly. I've updated the answer.